# pass jQuery value to php

Tags: jquery

for example, i have got this value in my php file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function altcat(id) {
        $ogzu = id;
    }
</script>
```

i want to use $ogzu value in php. is it possible? can i pass a value to php from jquery? i need to learn this answer.

can anyone help me please?
thanks and regards

### edit:

thanks for your kindly replies. i wanted to use $ogzu value in php like that:

```
<?php
echo "<a href='".$ogzu."'>test link</a>";
?>
```

well, i know its wrong. its already not working. i want to learn if we are able to use jquery values in php? thanks again friends. regards

Answer (score 2):

You can use ajax something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url:'yourfile.php',
  type:'GET',
  data: {id:yourVariable},
  success:function(res){
    // code
  }
});
```

Comment: This is a bad way to construct a string, what if it had a `&` for example?

Comment: @Nick Craver: That's a different story then, i do not assume the same here otherwise you are right one would take appropriate measures.

Comment: @Sarfraz - Why *ever* do it this unsafe way?  I disagree, you *do* assume here, you're assuming the value is safe...if you do it with an object you're not assuming anything, and there will be no issues.

Comment: im going to test your way right now... it may helps me. thanks for your reply.

Comment: The proper way would be using `data: { id: yourVariable }`

Comment: To safely return values (even with '&' and other special characters), use: http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/ or similar (if sending a form: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Answer (score 1):

You can POST ([`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) for shorthand) or GET ([`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) for shorthand) to PHP, whichever is needed, for example:

```
$.post("myPage.php", { id: $ogzu }, function(data) {
  alert("Response from server: " + data);
});
```

If you want it to be included in a `<form>` you're already submitting, just set the hidden input to that value, for example:

```
<input type="hidden" id="ogzu" name="ogzu" />
```

And matching script:

```
function altcat(id) {
   $("#ogzu").val(id);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your kindly reply dear mate. i edited my first message. i tested your way. its working, however by that way, i still cant use jquery value in php.. :(

Comment: @andrew - It won't be that variable exactly, it's the POSTed variable, `"id"` in my first `$.post()` sample above...so you'd replace `"<a href='".$ogzu."'>test link</a>"` with `"<a href='".$_POST["id"]."'>test link</a>"`

Comment: thanks Nick. i tested your way. ive gotten : response from server: (html codes of page, very long alert). well, i think there is no way to use a juery value in the php. actually, i wanted to use it within a lightbox. im getting value via form by using jquery and i wanted to echo values without refreshing the page.. anyway, thanks mate.